# Mysql query that replaces a unknown number in a path

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that you have the following stored in table:

{2:22}{4:5}{34:4}

I what to delete {4:5} from this string but the system dosent know what the number after the ":" is just the first one. The query looks something like this:

UPDATE `tbl` SET `this` = REPLACE(`this`,'{4:??}','') WHERE `id` = 1;

What do i need to put in ?? place to return the following result?

{2:22}{34:4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`, `LOCATE` and `REPLACE`:

```
update yourtable 
set yourcolumn = 
    replace(yourcolumn,
        Left(
            Substring(yourcolumn, 
                 Locate('{4:',yourcolumn),
                 Length(yourcolumn)),
        Locate('}',Substring(yourcolumn, 
                 Locate('{4:',yourcolumn),
                 Length(yourcolumn)))), 
        '')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/651aa/1)

Comment: thanks at first i was thinking that there is some simple way of doing this but yours actually worked